# Regex to find multiple matches

Tags: python, regex

i have tried some possibilities of lookahead to find a pattern inside a string, but I am stuck here as I have to check multiple conditions.

I have a string like

```
string = ''' i was behind the bars for (5.75) years '''
string2 = ''' I travelled for 6 months in Switzerland and some years say 5.2 in England '''
re.search(r'(?=\byears\b)([/d]+\S+)',str,re.I)
```

This I tried for get dates after years; `/S+` is used to get `5.33`, `5.44` etc. as there will be a space after the digit combination.

I want a regex to match any digit combination like `5.75`, `10.25` etc., even if it is enclosed in brackets or quotes. But I need the digits only. It can be before the word "years" or after it. What would be the best way to use regex in Python to check the multiple possibilities?

Comment: What are the possibilities that you tried, and how were they insufficient?

Comment: Just wait I will post it as comment .

Comment: Post it **in your question** as well as expected input and output

Comment: A simple integer parse regex is `(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)` What does "years" have to do with it ?

Comment: @sin -  I was looking not just dates. I will search if 'years' is there, if so I need to check whether there is a digit combination before or after the word "years". because it is a huge text and different possibilities of numbers are there.

Comment: `6 months in Switzerland and some years say 5.2` has two numbers surrounding "years". Can you clarify what it is you're doing ?

Comment: @sln - Hey dude. Just think a huge corpus. The possibility of word years is limited in my context, but digits are plent. if there is year or years , I need to traverse backwards and forwards [to maximium one line,or 2 lines], to check if there is a digit combination. If so I can proceed to next level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work.

**Update**

You're getting an 'invalid expression' error.
I don't see anything invalid unless python doesn't support modifiers in cluster groups.
You might try to take the case modifier out and adding it to the options part in the regex function.

Try this then:

```
(?:\b(\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)\b.*?(?:(?:\r?\n).*?){0,2}\byears?\b|\byears?\b.*?(?:(?:\r?\n).*?){0,2}\b(\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)\b)
```

*Original:*

```
 #  (?i:\b(\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)\b.*?(?:(?:\r?\n).*?){0,2}\byears?\b|\byears?\b.*?(?:(?:\r?\n).*?){0,2}\b(\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)\b)

 (?i:
      \b 
      (                             # (1 start), Digits
           \d+ 
           (?: \. \d* )?
        |  \. \d+ 
      )                             # (1 end)
      \b 
      .*? 
      (?:                           # 0, 1 or 2 lines
           (?: \r? \n )
           .*? 
      ){0,2}
      \b years? \b                  # Followed by "year(s)"

   |                              # or --

      \b years? \b                  # "year(s)"
      .*?   
      (?:                           # 0, 1 or 2 lines
           (?: \r? \n )
           .*? 
      ){0,2}
      \b 
      (                             # (2 start), Followed by Digits
           \d+ 
           (?: \. \d* )?
        |  \. \d+ 
      )                             # (2 end)
      \b 
 )
```

Comment: @sin - Thank man . it is not working. But i am making some modification and if it works fine i will post the answer here.

Comment: @sin - I have edited your answer with the error I encountered.

Comment: `Invalid expression` but doesn't say where. I've updated it to take out the case insensitive modifier, see if that works.

Comment: @sin - Works perfectly . How you guys are doing this. Its so complicated to me. Wow. Works like charm.

Comment: @sin - Thanks for being helpful.